# Add missing years in a date time column and fill the new rows with nan values in the rest of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks as follows:

[image]

I want to add missing years in the 'date' column so that it starts from year 2002 and ends in 2020 and fill `nan` values in the corresponding rows of the 'party_count' column.
Additionally, I hope to fill all the new rows of the 'country' column with the same 'Georgia' values.

I would appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can generate a list from 2002 to 2020, create a DataFrame with `date` and `country` columns, and then merge it with the original DF.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'country': ['Georgia']*5, 
        'date': [2003, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016], 
        'party_count': [6.0, 3.0, 6.0, 2.0, 3.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dates = list(range(2002, 2021)) 
df_all = pd.DataFrame({'country': 'Georgia', 'date': dates})
df_merged = pd.merge(df_all, df, how='left', on=['country', 'date']) 
print(df_merged)
```

**Output**

|  | country | date | party_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Georgia | 2002 | NaN |
| 1 | Georgia | 2003 | 6.0 |
| 2 | Georgia | 2004 | 3.0 |
| 3 | Georgia | 2005 | NaN |
| 4 | Georgia | 2006 | NaN |
| 5 | Georgia | 2007 | NaN |
| 6 | Georgia | 2008 | 6.0 |
| 7 | Georgia | 2009 | NaN |
| 8 | Georgia | 2010 | NaN |
| 9 | Georgia | 2011 | NaN |
| 10 | Georgia | 2012 | 2.0 |
| 11 | Georgia | 2013 | NaN |
| 12 | Georgia | 2014 | NaN |
| 13 | Georgia | 2015 | NaN |
| 14 | Georgia | 2016 | 3.0 |
| 15 | Georgia | 2017 | NaN |
| 16 | Georgia | 2018 | NaN |
| 17 | Georgia | 2019 | NaN |
| 18 | Georgia | 2020 | NaN |